# Can't install stof doctrine extension bundle for symfony v3.0.1

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to install StofDoctrineExtensionBundle and I'm using symfony2 v3.0 but I get errors when I launch the composer's command.
This is my composer.json:

```
"require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony" : "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "~2.2",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1" #The bundle I want to install
    }
```

When I launch this command on my composer.phar:

```
php ../composer.phar update
```

The console shows me these errors:

```
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.8.0, v2.8.1].
    - stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.8.0, v2.8.1].
    - stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.2.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.8.0, v2.8.1].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle ~1.1 -> satisfiable by stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.2.1].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the latest release 1.2.1 doesn't include the support of SF3.

But, `composer.json` of the master branch has been updated to include this support.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.1|~3.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.3.1"
},
```

So you could use it for testing purpose. If there is no official release, I would not using it in production.

```
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master"
```